# Why are build dependencies of a package incomplete?

Tags: apt, dependencies, source-packages

The [build dependencies of rsync](https://packages.ubuntu.com/source/hirsute/rsync) are:

- debhelper-compat (= 13)
- libacl1-dev
- libpopt-dev
- liblz4-dev
- libxxhash-dev
- libzstd-dev
- zlib1g-dev
- libssl-dev

If I install all these packages, I still have no C++ compiler.  This is done deliberately, I assume, but why?  And which packages must be added to make the list complete?

Comment: The compiler is the tool you use to build it. Not a dependency.

Comment: https://packages.ubuntu.com/source/focal/rust-ripgrep contains the Rust compiler. Besides, I cannot know which compilers are needed for a package (or, whether compilers are needed at all).

Comment: Possibly, `build-essential` is special-cased, and implicit for every build?

Comment: `sudo apt-get build-dep rsync` will do all for you.

Comment: Yes, however, I need to post-process the list of packages. (It is about building Emacs, that wants to have Postfix installed, which is too much of a dependency in my case.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The list of dependencies is complete. To build a package under Ubuntu you need some requirements : `build-essential`, `fakeroot` and  `devscripts`:

```
sudo apt install build-essential fakeroot devscripts
```